Zod allow all keys matching regex
I'm using zod to validate some data, and I want to allow certain attributes, as well as any attribute with key matching /metadata_hash_.*/.
I cannot simply use a record because I am using mixed types, and need to specify individual attribute types.
Say for example this schema:
import { z } from "zod";

const schema = z.object({
  a: z.number(),
  b: z.number()
});

Now I want to allow any attribute matching /metadata_hash_.*/: z.string(). I've tried:

Merging with a record object, but that was not allowed
using .catchall, but I did not find a way to check the key, only the value
using z.preprocess and converting the keys into an object and validating that as a z.record(z.string().refine(...), z.string()),
but this changes the shape of the object which I don't really want.

Is there a good way to do this?

It seems that it's possibe to use Record with Union, and, or and Discriminated unions for this case.
A Record with Union:
const schema1 = z.record( 
    z.string().regex(/metadata_hash_.*/),  
      z.union([
        z.string(), 
        z.number()
    ])  
);

//Success
console.log(schema1.safeParse({
  "metadata_hash_XXXXX":"string",
  "metadata_hash_XXXXX":1111
}));

A Record with double Union:
const schema2 = z.record( 
  z.union([
    z.string().regex(/metadata_hash_.*/), 
    z.string().regex(/metadata_number_[0-9]*/)
 ]),  
    z.union([
      z.string(), 
      z.number()
  ])  
);

//Success
console.log(schema2.safeParse({
"metadata_hash_XXXXX":"string",
"metadata_hash_12":1111
}));

A Union with double Record
const schema3 = z.union([
  z.record( z.string().regex(/metadata_hash_.*/), z.string() ), 
  z.record( z.string().regex(/metadata_number_[0-9]*/), z.number() )
]);

console.log(schema3.safeParse({
"metadata_hash_XXXXX":"string1",
"metadata_hash_XXXXX":"string2",
}));

console.log(schema3.safeParse({
  "metadata_number_12":111,
  "metadata_number_12":112
  }));

